# How do I render human-readable value in HTML of a choice list?

Tags: python, django

Using the following model to select a day of the week:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    DAYS_OF_WEEK = [
        (0, 'Monday'),
        (1, 'Tuesday'),
        (2, 'Wednesday'),
        (3, 'Thursday'),
        (4, 'Friday'),
        (5, 'Saturday'),
        (6, 'Sunday')
    ]
    day_of_week = models.IntegerField(choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK, default=0)
```

Rendering the models in HTML via `{{ schedule.day_of_week }}` renders the integer value of 0-6 rather than the human-readable "Monday-Sunday" values.

When I view the model in the admin panel, I see the human readable values.

How do I render the human readable values in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "human-readable" value can be displayed by using [**`get_FOO_display`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display), so:

```
{{ schedule.get_day_of_week_display }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for generating a days only list on the fly
`choices=[i[1] for i in DAYS_OF_WEEK]`